# How do I get the 3 times array in for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am not familiar with `c/c++`, but when I am trying to implement a `for loop` statement I have the following error:

> error C2296: '*' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned char *'

```
unsigned char *_Orgin_Pixel_;
unsigned char *_Copy_Pixel_;
....

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Picture_x_ * Picture_y_; i++)
{
    *(_Copy_Pixel_*3 + i) = _Orgin_Pixel_[i];
}
```

How do I resolve that problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `_Copy_Pixel_*3`? Are you trying to copy the original pixels to every third pixel? (BTW I hope you have malloc/newed the arrays, and don't forget to free them later)

Comment: `_Copy_Pixel_ + 3 * i` ? or `_Copy_Pixel_ + 3 * i + 0`, `_Copy_Pixel_ + 3 * i + 1` and `_Copy_Pixel_ + 3 * i + 2` ?

Comment: Just to be clear, it is illegal to multiple a pointer by anything. It just makes no sense to do so.

Comment: I resolve that problem like this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem. as below,

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Picture_x_ * Picture_y_; i++)
{
    *(_Copy_Pixel_ + i * 3 + 0) = _Orgin_Pixel_[i];
    *(_Copy_Pixel_ + i * 3 + 1) = _Orgin_Pixel_[i];
    *(_Copy_Pixel_ + i * 3 + 2) = _Orgin_Pixel_[i];
}
```

What if I want to separate as 2 cascade, why do they different?

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Picture_y_ ; i++)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Picture_x_ ; j++)
{
    _Copy_Pixel_[(i*Picture_y_  + j *3+ 0)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[i*Picture_y_ + j];//B
    _Copy_Pixel_[(i*Picture_y_  + j*3 + 1)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[i*Picture_y_ + j];//G
    _Copy_Pixel_[(i*Picture_y_  + j*3 + 2)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[i*Picture_y_ + j];//R
}
```

I can't understand, did I miss something?

Comment: Which in turn could be de-obfuscated into `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Picture_x_ * Picture_y_; i++) for(unsigned int j=0; j<3; j++) _Copy_Pixel_[i*3+j] = _Orgin_Pixel_[i];`